# Change text(number) on all next elements on dynamically appended div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating survey with Questions and SubQuestions who have numbers.

There are 3 questions with order numbers ex. 1, 2... The No.2 question have 2 SubSections with questions in it.

The number of the first SubSection is 2.1 and the numbers of questions are 2.1.1, 2.1.2 ...
The second SubSection have number 2.2 and the numbers of questions are 2.2.1, 2.2.2 ...

I am dynamically appending div elmement(question) after the first question (No.1) with No.2 as order number. I want the other order numbers of the questions and the questions into the SubSections to go up by one.
Ex. 3 -> 3.1 -> 3.1.1 -> 3.1.2  / 3.2 -> 3.2.1 -> 3.2.2, next question from 3 to 4...

```
$('#btn').on('click', function(){
debugger;
  //$('body').find('.holder').prepend($('#newQuestion').html());
  $('body').find('.question-holder').eq(0).append($('#newQuestion').html());
  var x = Number($('body').find('.question-holder').eq(2).closest('.question-holder').find('.order-number').html()) + 1;
  $('body').find('.question-holder').eq(2).closest('.question-holder').find('.order-number').text(x);

})
```

Here is my [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gjn9hgjh/1/) .

Comment: You have no answer input field ? Maybe it would be easyier to add the next question based which answer contains a value...

Comment: I have answer input on my application. I have made this JsFiddle for example. The main thing that i'm doing is that i'm inserting Question, and setting the numbers of the other questions.

Comment: I dont know... It look pretty complex to achieve a simple thing. I would just display:block the next question to be shown onblur of an answer.